# Join using Table valued function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

How can I do a join using table valued function i MSSql 2012 like the query below?

```
SELECT  m1.id, m1.oid, m1.id2
FROM    dbo.Match(484066) AS m1 INNER JOIN
        dbo.Match(m1.id2) AS m2 ON m1.id2 = m2.id INNER JOIN
        dbo.Match(m2.id2) AS m3 ON m2.id2 = m3.id AND m1.id = m3.id2
```

Comment: Or even better, is it possible to rewrite the function using recursive calls on result to get the same result? (lovely would be to have a parameter telling how many times it should do a recursive call, the last call it should always check id2 with 484066(m1.id))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  m1.id, m1.oid, m1.id2
FROM    dbo.Match(484066) AS m1 CROSS APPLY
        dbo.Match(m1.id2) AS m2 CROSS APPLY
        dbo.Match(m2.id2) AS m3
```

Is this all you wanted?

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks :)